# How to output the monero-cli-wallet commands using --comand "status" without all the other output data?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, cli

```
./monero-wallet-cli --wallet-file=XXXX --daemon-address YYYYY --command "balance"
```

When I use the above command, it gives me the ability to see my balance, but how do I make it where it doesn't output the startup message when monero cli starts?

[image]

End result, I just want to be able to output the balance and save it to a file or pass it into an argument of another command like grep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I use the above command, it gives me the ability to see my balance, but how do I make it where it doesn't output the startup message when monero cli starts?

The simplest way (*nix) is:

```
monero-wallet-cli --wallet-file your-wallet --password 'your-password' \
    --command balance | tail -2
```

You can of course pipe through anything that accepts data on stdin.

Another example:

```
monero-wallet-cli --wallet-file your-wallet --password 'your-password' \
    --command accounts | tail -n +15 | head -n -3
```

Removes the header and footer from `accounts` output displaying everything in between.

Comment: but that wouldnt work for a command like 'account' which could have many subaddresses.

Comment: You asked specifically wrt the "balance" command. You can pipe any command output and parse however you like with tail, grep, sed, awk etc etc.